Replace nth character in string with condition
I’m doing some data tidying and I need to find a way to replace some characters in a bunch of cells. For instance I would need to remove the 1st character if it’s a 0 and also the 3rd character if it is a 0.
Here’s an example of what I’d like to do :
01001 -> 101
11003 -> 1103
08011 -> 811
I’ve tried using stri_replace_all_regex but I can’t manage to find a regex that’ll work for this. I’m only managing to delete a whole part of the string with something like ^..0 Maybe there’s a better way ?
Thanks in advance !

I am not that proficient with regex, but I hope the sub attempt can help
> (x <- c("01001", "11003", "08011"))
[1] "01001" "11003" "08011"

> sub("^0", "", sub("(?<=^.{2})0(?=.)", "", x, perl = TRUE))
[1] "101"  "1103" "811"


Hi and thanks for your answer. Looks like that worked ! Could you explain how the "(?<=^.{2})0(?=.)" regex works ? I tried looking up some documentation by myself but couldn’t get there so I’d like to understand :)

I found this page useful to explain the lookahead and lookbehind regexes.

Building a function to do the deletion
strdelete_pos <- function(strg, pos, is) sapply(strsplit(strg, ""), \(x) 
  paste0(lapply(seq_along(x), \(y) 
    if(x[y] == is & (any(y == pos))) "" else x[y]), collapse=""))

Apply
strdelete_pos(c("01001", "11003", "08011"), c(1,3), "0")
[1] "101"  "1103" "811"


You could combine string manipulation functions with case_when:
library("tidyverse")

string <- c("01001", "11003", "08011", "0111")

 case_when(
  # if first and third characters are 0
  str_detect(string, "^0.0") ~ str_replace(string, "^(.)(.)(.)", paste0("", "\\2", "")),
  # if first character is a zero
  str_detect(string, "^0") ~ str_replace(string, "^0", ""),
  # if third character is a zero
  str_detect(string, "^.{2}0") ~ str_replace(string, "^(.{2}).", paste0("\\1", "")),
  # otherwise keep original string
  TRUE ~ string
)

